# I am trying to get the "MEAL" rate from the GSA API

Tags: json, vb.net

Using VB.NET
Here is my HTTP request:

https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b&filters={%22FiscalYear%22:%222017%22,%22Zip%22:%2290210%22}

(sorry I can not get the link to format properly)

I get the response and parse it. I am having trouble extracting only the 'Meal' rate from what is returned.

```
Dim json As String = responseFromServer
Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList
Dim output As String = ""

For Each item As JProperty In data
    --> Not sure what to do in here.
Next
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The 'Meal' rate, as in the `"Meals": "64"` value?  Something like `Dim mealRate = CInt(ser("result")("records")(0)("Meals"))`?

Comment: This was it exactly. Thank you so much for a clear answer to my not so clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned from the API looks like this (some data removed to save space):

```
{
  "help": "https://inventory.data.gov/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search",
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "resource_id": "8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b",
    "fields": [
      ...snip...
    ],
    "records": [
      {
        "City": "Los Angeles",
        "Dec": "158",
        "Feb": "175",
        "Zip": "90210",
        "Aug": "158",
        "Sep": "158",
        "Apr": "158",
        "Jun": "158",
        "State": "CA",
        "Jul": "158",
        "Meals": "64",
        "County": "Los Angeles County, CA",
        "May": "158",
        "DestinationID": "22",
        "Mar": "175",
        "Jan": "175",
        "LocationDefined": "Los Angeles / Orange / Ventura / Edwards AFB less the city of Santa Monica",
        "Nov": "158",
        "_id": 39056,
        "Oct": "158",
        "FiscalYear": "2017"
      }
    ],
    "_links": {
      "start": "/api/action/datastore_search?filters=%7B%22FiscalYear%22%3A%222017%22%2C%22Zip%22%3A%2290210%22%7D&resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b",
      "next": "/api/action/datastore_search?offset=100&filters=%7B%22FiscalYear%22%3A%222017%22%2C%22Zip%22%3A%2290210%22%7D&resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b"
    },
    "filters": {
      "Zip": "90210",
      "FiscalYear": "2017"
    },
    "total": 1
  }
}
```

Once you have parsed the data to a `JObject` you can simply drill down through the structure to get the value that you want:

```
Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim mealRate = CInt(ser("result")("records")(0)("Meals"))
```